# Использование js-переменных внутри переменных freemarker

Tags: javascript, java, freemarker

Есть список, option'ы которого - ключи Map.

```
<select id="list">
   <#list map?keys as key>
    <option>${key}</option>
   <#/list>
</select>
```

И есть input'ы, значения которых должны браться из значений Map в зависимости от выбранного элемента списка.

```
<input id="field1" type="text">
<input id="field2" type="text">
<input id="field3" type="text">
```

В js пробовал использовать следующее:

```
let selectedValue = $('#list').val();
let field1 = $('#field1');
let field2 = $('#field2');
let field3 = $('#field3');
field1.val(${map[selectedValue].field1});
field2.val(${map[selectedValue].field2});
field3.val(${map[selectedValue].field3});
```

Это не заработало, freemarker ищет selectedValue в модели.

Можно ли каким-либо образом использовать переменные js в составе переменных freemarker? Или заполнить input'ы значениями полей объекта из map можно как-то по-другому?

Comment: Так, а можешь показать часть кода с options и inputs  целиком? Value - это список? Или почему инпутов несколько?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let selected = $('#select').val();
            let elements = {
                <#list map as key, value>
                '${key}' : {
                    field1 : '${value.field1}',
                    field2 : '${value.field2}',
                    field3 : '${value.field3}'
                },
                </#list>
            };
            if (selected !== '' && selected !== null) {
                $('#field1').val(elements[selected].field1);
                $('#field2').val(elements[selected].field2);
                $('#field3').val(elements[selected].field3);
            }
```

Воспользоваться js-переменными внутри freemarker так и не вышло, но можно построить js-объект из `Map` (см. код выше), обернуть его в функцию и привязать к событию `onchange`. Возможно, это не самый оптимальный подход.

Answer (score 1):

С JavaScript'ом не помогу, но средствами freemarker это можно(если я правильно понял вопрос) сделать примерно так:
Допустим, у тебя такой `Map`:

```
Map<String, YourObject> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Тогда будет что-то вроде этого:

```
<select id="list">
    <#list yourMap as key, value>
        <option>${key}</option>

        //another code

        <input id="field1" type="text" value="${{value.getFirstParam()}/>
        <input id="field2" type="text" value="${value.getSecondParam()}/>
        <input id="field3" type="text" value="${value.getThirdParam()}/>
    </#list>
</select>
```

Comment: Увы, но в такой реализации получится много списков с одним вариантом выбора по количеству ключей, как и наборов input'ов. Должен получиться один select со всеми ключами `Map`, и inputs, в которые пишутся определённые поля из соответствующего выбранному в select ключу `YourObject`.

Comment: @НикитаКушнеров да, вы правы, я опечатался. Нужно тэг `<#list>` внести внутрь `select`. В итоге будет один `options` на каждый элемент `list` и уникальные значения input для каждого из них

Comment: Пока `input`внутри `<#list></#list>`, он будет создаваться на каждой итерации, а мне нужно менять содержимое одного набора `input`, а не создавать новый набор полей для каждой `options`.

Comment: Собственно, из-за подобных проблем я и решил обрабатывать `onchange` списка, получать в js значение select и затем попросту получить объект по полученному ключу и в js заполнить существующие `input`, а не создавать их динамически. Что из этого получилось - вы видели в самом вопросе.